# on the convergence exponent of zeros of entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{z_j\}$ be the sequence of zeros on an entire function $f$. We define the convergence exponent of $\{z_j\}$ as
$$b=\inf\left\{\lambda>0\ \text{s.t.}\ \sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{|z_j|^{\lambda}}<+\infty\right\}$$
Let $n(r)$ be the number of $z_j$'s with $|z_j|\leq r$. Then the following identity holds:
$$b=\limsup_{r\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\log{\ n(r)}}{\log{r}}$$
Do you think i should use Jensen formula to prove this?

Comment: I think this should be possible to show straightforwardly. If $n(r)>r^\lambda$ infinitely often, then ...

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @haigen von eitzen suppose i know $\lim_{r\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{n(r)}{r^{\lambda}}=0$. What could i deduce from this?

Comment: @greg martin a part of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: note that
$$
\sum_{j\colon U\le |z_j|<2U} \frac1{|z_j|^\lambda} \le \sum_{j\colon U\le |z_j|<2U} \frac1{U^\lambda} \le \frac{n(2U)}{U^\lambda}.
$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac1{|z_j|^\lambda} &\le \sum_{j\colon |z_j|<1} \frac1{|z_j|^\lambda} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j\colon 2^{k-1}\le |z_j|<2^k} \frac1{|z_j|^\lambda} \\
&\le \text{(finite number of terms)} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n(2^k)}{(2^{k-1})^\lambda}.
\end{align*}
In this way, knowledge about the growth of $n(r)$ can be converted into bounds on the sum in question. Lower bounds can be handled similarly.

Comment: thank you very much, but i can't understand the second line in your answer. we have $\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{|z_j|^{\lambda}}=$ sum of finite number of terms +$\sum_{U=1}^{+\infty}(\displaystyle\sum_{U\leq|z_j|<2U}\frac{1}{|z_j|^{\lambda}})\leq\sum_{U=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n(2U)}{U^{\lambda}}$ and how can i get your second line?

Comment: sorry, I had a typo in there - and I added another step while I was at it, hopefully better now